# run single operation in RxJS after mutliple items are processed

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm relatively new to RxJs and am unable to chain a single operation after processing multiple items emitted using switchMap operator.

Scenario: use backend data to generate an object array for a dropdownlist, then chain a single operation to set the dropdown's selected value.

Here's the non-working code that helps illustrate the problem.

```
this.sub = this.dataService.getUserData()
    .switchMap((data) => Observable.from(data)) // create new data stream from inner data set
    .map((data: any) => {
        return { value: data._id, viewValue: data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName };
    }) // create data structure for drop down
    .subscribe( (data) => {
        this.userDropDown.push(data); // this operation needs to run once per item emitted, and is working
        this.patchFormData(); // <-- However, this only needs to run once
    },
    (error) => console.log("error", error)
    );
```

I've tried various operators that morph the problem but am unable to solve the entirety of the issue i.e. a) get new object array based off the source data and b) run a single operation after completion.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

- S. Arora

--  UPDATE: working final version is here based on answer below with minor syntax fix:

```
this.sub = this.dataService.getUserData()
    .map((data: any[]) => {
        return data.map((x: any) => {
            return { value: x._id, viewValue: x.firstName + ' ' + x.lastName };
        });
    })
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.userDropDown = data;
        this.patchFormData();
    },
    (error) => console.log("error", error)
    );
```

Comment: is `this.dataService.getUserData()` returning an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you do not need the `.switchMap()` at all. You are just creating multiple emissions using `Observable.from()`,which is completely unnecessary unless you really want to update your dropdown values one by one.

What you could do is just returning the array, use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the array, and then assign it to your dropdown value list.

```
this.sub = this.dataService.getUserData()
//this map is a function of Observable
    .map((data: any[]) => {
        //this map is a function of array, not observable.
        //use this to transform the data
        return data.map(x => ({value: x._id, viewValue: x.firstName + ' ' + x.lastName}))
    })
    .subscribe((data) => {
            //assign your values to your dropdown list, and not pushing it one by one.
            this.userDropDown = data;
            this.patchFormData();
        },
        (error) => console.log("error", error)
    );
```

Now, you only have one emission in your Observable (which is the api call), and then in your `.subscribe()` function, your `this.userDropDown` and `this.patchFormData()` will both only run once.

Comment: Unfortunately the .switchmap serves a need..the getUserData call relies on graphql which offers me a single collection of users to work with. switchMap converts that single collection into separately emitted items (one per user) which i can then transform one-by-one using map. I thought of using lodash to work with the entire collection but am trying to stick to RxJs approach if possible.

Comment: @sarora that is exactly the point of my answer, that you **do not** need to transform them one-by-one via the observables. You can transform them using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) of array.

Comment: THANK YOU! I didn't think to manipulate the collection with regular .map operator *within* the RxJs pipeline..very nifty! Once I got into the .switchmap approach it made it unnecessarily difficult to chain a single operation.